# how to get the value of combobox selected item in python

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

```
selectedfood = tk.StringVar() 

foodselectionUI = ttk.Combobox(homeUI, width = 27, textvariable = selectedfood) 

foodselectionUI['values'] = ("None", "Nasi Ayam", "Maggi Mee Goreng", "Wan Tan Mee", "Nasi Lemak","Nasi Ayam Tiga Rasa", "Ayam Goreng", "Sushi", "Burger Special","Vega Bao", "Kari Ayam Bao","select food") 

foodselectionUI.place(x = 10, y = 125, width = 150) 

foodselectionUI.current(11)
```

this is my code 
and this picture is my tkinter UI

[image]

may i know how to get my selection

for example if user choose 'sushi' i can get it as my **textvariable**

i didnt get my output using this way

i get this thing `PY_VAR1`

Comment: When and how do you get the selected item?  Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
def justamethod (*args):
    print("method is called")
    print (selectedfood.get())
foodselectionUIbind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", justamethod)
```

Comment: `foodselectionUIbind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", justamethod())` should be `foodselectionUI.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", justamethod)`.

Comment: There are still issues in your code: 1) function definition should be declared before the binding, otherwise exception `NameError: name 'justamethod' is not defined` will be raised; 2) `foodselectionUIbind.get()` should be `selectedfood.get()`.